# Make button below another view using ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a layout with 1 `Button` (have red background) and 2 `ImageView` (one have yellow background and one have blue background) like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#f00"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#ff0"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#00f"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the result image, the `Button` displays above 2 `ImageView`. After test I see that this problem only happened with `Button`. If in my layout code, I remove the `Button`, 2 remain `ImageView` display correct .

[image]

How to make a centered `Button` display below another view using `ConstraintLayout`?. Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Comment: Did the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47458578/6891637) I posted help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the button has a default elevation of `2dp`. See this [link](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-elevation-android)

An easy fix would be to set the elevation of the `ImageView` as `3dp` or more.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**EDIT**

For API below 21 (Lolipop) this should not be a problem, and the view will be rendered correctly (in the order of placement in XML). And since we are to use `android:elevation` to get other views above the `Button`, it is important that we create a separate layout resource for API 21+

Comment: Never thought that elevation might bring such problems. Thanks for catching it!

Comment: sorry for later response because currently I stop use ConstraintLayout. I test this solution and found that `android:elevation="2dp"` work but it require API 21 or higher. Is there any solution for lower API

Comment: @PhanVanLinh Elevation comes into play only on API 21 and above. For API 19 it works exactly as you intended without having to specify the elevation. So you will have to create a seperate layout resource for API 21+

Comment: @AjilO. Thank you for the helpful information. Please note it to your answer to make it more valuable